# Unable to launch Jupyter Notebook with Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I keep getting this error whenever I try to launch Jupyter. No idea what does it mean.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\crimi\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\crimi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 43, in 
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
File "C:\Users\crimi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from markupsafe import escape
ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'markupsafe' (unknown location)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having problems with the library `markupsafe`, which is probably not installed or properly upgraded. I suggest you to open the terminal, activate the conda environment that you are using, and upgrade the package. You can use the following instruction:

```
pip install markupsafe --upgrade
```